# Java cache on JBoss

Tags: java, caching, jboss

I have a Java Application running on a *JBOSS*.
This application gets data from several *APIs* and shows it on a webpage.

I want to cache the data so it doesn't need to call the APIs every time someone opens my webpage.

I want to cache 5 Lists or Strings for like 5 minutes. Is there any way to do it without a database?

Comment: what framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http sesion to persist information

Example

```
HttpSession misession= request.getSession(true);
Producto miproducto= new Producto(1,"telefono",300);
misession.setAttribute("producto",miproducto);
```

Link

[HttpSession JBoss](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

Documenation

[Jbos](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/development_guide/sect-httpsession_passivation_and_activation)

If you are using springboot

You can use a singleton with application annotation

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public PrototypeBean prototypeBean() {
        return new PrototypeBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public SingletonBean singletonBean() {
        return new SingletonBean();
    }
}

public class SingletonBean {

    // ..

    @Autowired
    private PrototypeBean prototypeBean;

    public SingletonBean() {
        logger.info("Singleton instance created");
    }

    public PrototypeBean getPrototypeBean() {
        logger.info(String.valueOf(LocalTime.now()));
        return prototypeBean;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context 
      = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    
    SingletonBean firstSingleton = context.getBean(SingletonBean.class);
    PrototypeBean firstPrototype = firstSingleton.getPrototypeBean();
    
    // get singleton bean instance one more time
    SingletonBean secondSingleton = context.getBean(SingletonBean.class);
    PrototypeBean secondPrototype = secondSingleton.getPrototypeBean();

    isTrue(firstPrototype.equals(secondPrototype), "The same instance should be returned");
}
```

if you are using primer faces, you cna use @ApplicationScoped

@ApplicationScoped

An application-scoped managed bean instance is tied to the lifetime of the web application itself. There’s only one instance of an application-scoped managed bean throughout your web application. It is not the same but similar to a Singleton EJB.

[Singleton](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton)

Comment: But here every user has its own Session. I want all users to use the same data.

Comment: Hello? Can you help me? Please!

Comment: Yes, i am going to update the code @Arnold2080